# Ideas for how to properly bring only new CSS styles to new branch

Tags: css, git

So my dilema is a bit strange, basically I'm in the middle of joining two different web branches and I need a more effective way to combine the CSS without overwriting anything.  Basically I have CSS files named the same way on both branches, but the CSS files are different and I just want to bring in all the elements from the old style that isn't already defined in the new CSS file.

Any ideas whatsoever will be greatly appreciated.  Right now what I have resorted to is painfully slow and unproductive.  I have to go one line at a time and find what css styles were applied to the element in the old version, and bring that over to the new version if it isn't already defined in a new way.

Thank you so much for any thoughts!

Answer (score -2):

```
Width:200 !important;
```

The important feature is used a lot by web developers, though i prefer to specify every element exactly the way as being used that way i don't have to worry about importance.
Using important is considered bad practice and should only be used in testing.

Comment: I believe the OP was referring to an actual overwrite, not __override__, during the merge between two git branches.

Comment: Well, i don't think he was.

Comment: Thanks guys... this problem is much more complicated than I first thought actually.  It's a combination of both.